# store array or vector in ms sql server 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql, sql-server-2008

Anyone knows how to store array or vector in ms sql server 2005? There is way to store array in oracle db but I don't know about sql server.

eg:

```
st_id [1234]
st_mk [(12),(34),(67),(45)]

st_id [3456]
st_mk [(12),(34)]
```

Like above `st_mk` (the vector size) is not same.

Please help me...!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a separate child table?

```
create table Vector(st_id int primary key)

create table VectorElement
(
    st_id int references Vector(st_id),
    element int
)

create index IX_VectorElement_st_id on VectorElement(st_id)

insert Vector
values(1234)

insert VectorElement
select 1234, 12 union all
select 1234, 34 union all
select 1234, 67 union all
select 1234, 45
```

Another option to store it as a string (`varchar`), but this is less efficient and you would need to parse it.

Another option is to use [XML type column](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522510.aspx).

Comment: I think VectorElement needs an ordinal column to maintain the order of the list elements.